# How to split an image in multipe parts for image processing, then recombine?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, image-processing, partitioning

I am using Core Image and GPUImage to make some filters in an iPhone app. I seem to be running out of memory and crashing with larger images. I think this can be solved if I can split the input image into multiple parts.

How to efficiently split an image in multiple parts for image processing, then recombine to output the resulting image as a whole in iOS?

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried with the latest code I've committed to the repository? I made some improvements to the memory usage within the framework that might help avoid crashes when working with large images. There's still more to be done, but this might help.

Comment: No, I'll try it. Thanks Brad!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)getMultipleImages:(UIImage*)image AndNumberOfPart:(NSInteger)matrixSize{



CGSize size = image.size;

//for storing rect values of puzzle boxess
NSMutableArray *puzzleRectArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *puzzleCroppedObj = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

int widthD = size.width;
int heightD = size.height;

float boxWidth = widthD/matrixSize;
float boxHeight = heightD/matrixSize;


for (int i = 0; i < matrixSize*matrixSize; i++) {

    int x = (widthD/matrixSize)/2 + (widthD/matrixSize) *(i%matrixSize)-boxWidth/2;
    int y = (heightD/matrixSize)/2 + (heightD/matrixSize)* (i/matrixSize)-boxHeight/2;


    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(x, y, boxWidth, boxHeight);
    [puzzleRectArr addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:rect]];

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([self.imgActual CGImage], rect);
    UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
//----------------------------------------------------------------------        
    //here You can find the part image
    [puzzleCroppedObj addObject:croppedImage];

//----------------------------------------------------------------------                


     CGImageRelease(imageRef);
}
}
```